# Angular ionic badge count not updating

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angular and believe i am not fully understanding the digest cycle. 
I am trying to update a badge count in a ion-tab.(using ionic)

"ion-tab"

```
<ion-tab title="Requests" badge="data.badge" ng-controller="RequestTabCtrl" badge-style="badge-assertive" icon-off="ion-pull-request" icon-on="ion-pull-request" href="#/tab/requests">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-requests"></ion-nav-view>
```

I have written a factory that will store and array. this array is updated through socket.io

"notifications factory"

```js
.factory('notifications',function(){
  var list = [];
  return{
    all: function(){
      return list;
    },
    add: function(data){
      list.push(data);
    },
    length: function(){
        return list.length;
    }
  };
});
```

```
.controller('RequestTabCtrl',function($scope,notifications){
  $scope.data = {
    badge : notifications.length()
    };
});
```

My problem is that the badge count is not updating when the notifications array is updated through socket.io. I have checked that the array is being updated. In fact i can console log the array length and can see it it changing. Also i have set a scope variable in the ion-tab's child io-nav-view and as a result can see the expression {{requests.length}} be updated in this view.

```
.controller('RequestsCtrl', function($scope,notifications) {
  $scope.requests = notifications.all();
})
```

I have tried $watch(in RequestTabCtrl) on notifications.length. i have tried calling $apply(in RequestTabCtrl) which results in a $digest already in progress. I have tried $timeout and see no positive result (in RequestTabCtrl and the factory length function). Help will me much appreciated.

Comment: How are you updating notifications array?

Comment: through socket.io. everytime i get a notifications i call the add method of the notifications factory.   mySocket.on('notification',function(data){
       
      notifications.add({name: data});

    });

Comment: May be thats why it's not updating badge count . The view binds to $scope variable not the factory So any change on factory will not reflect on view.

Comment: but i have injected the factory into the controller.

Comment: Just for testing put a button on view and increment $scope.data.badge on button click .it should increment the badge count.This will help you to understand problem.

Comment: based on my understanding you need to use some background process (like $interval) which will keep running and fetching the updated notifications count and assign to $scope variable.

Comment: @AjinderSingh which view? the RequestTabCtrl is and ion-tab. the RequestsCtrl is the view that you see when you click on the tab. Also i am pretty sure if i do that in the RequestsCtrl view it will update the badge. i tried this approach but with an input field and a ng-model

Comment: i'm not familier with Ionic but it seems you are not updating the $scope badge variable value. Please see and try my last comment

Comment: @AjinderSingh I agree with you. But i am asking how can i update this, not from a button press, but automatically as soon as the array has changed size. Thanks

Comment: as i said above some background process like $interval which will keep running and monitor if notifications array changes and assign to scope variable.

Comment: oh sorry i did not see that comment. i will try that. thanks alot

Comment: No worries!! Let me know how it goes

Comment: @AjinderSingh i tried $interval and it worked. Firstly thanks. now is this the best way of solving this. i though i should be able to use $apply or $ digest in the factory or controller to handle updating the $scope?

Comment: I think you can also $broadcast event from your factory when notification added like $rootScope.$broadcast('name-of-controller-method-here') which get called whenever notification added via socket.io

Comment: @AjinderSingh You are a star. $broadcast did the trick. I dont know how to accept answers in the comments, but if you add your post as an answer i will certainly accept it.

Comment: Glad that it helps you. May be add some of your working code as answer so it help other users .

Comment: @AjinderSingh curious if you know what I might be doing wrong here? Seems like I screwing up scoping somewhere. Checkout my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470828/angular-ionic-badge-count-not-updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to AjinderSingh, the solution was found.

So two ways to go about this. First using the $interval approach:

```
.controller('RequestTabCtrl',function($scope,notifications,$interval){
    $interval(function(){
       $scope.data = {
           badge : notifications.length()
        };
    },2000);
});
```

Second approach is to $broadcast from the factory after an item has been added to the array. followed by catching this event in the controller:

```
.factory('notifications',function($rootScope){
  var list = [];
  return{
    all: function(){
      return list;
    },
    add: function(data){
      list.push(data);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('update');
    },
    length: function(){
        return list.length;
    }
  };
});


.controller('RequestTabCtrl',function($scope,notifications,$interval){
      $scope.$on('update',function(){
           $scope.data = {
              badge : notifications.length()
            };
       });
 });
```

I am choosing the second approach as it seems to be cleaner.

Comment: it wont allow me until two days have passed.

Comment: No problem . Mark it later . I will also suggest you to checkout https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide .I'm sure you'll like it

Answer (score 0):

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaBadge.promptForPermission();

    $scope.setBadge = function(value) {
        $cordovaBadge.hasPermission().then(function(result) {
            $cordovaBadge.set(value);
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    }
});
```

For complete reference plz check https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/07/modify-the-badge-number-of-an-ionic-framework-app/