# how to update data to front end table while if any changes has occurred in database table records using angular js and grails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, websocket

how to update data to view while if any changes (insert | update |
delete) has occurred in database table records using Angularjs and
grails.

Now I just have `$interval` function inside my controller.

**what i am exactly need means, when a user update something from one browser, it will automatically update in all user browser who have view this page view.**

My Code:

```
$interval(function(){
    if($('#arrivalDepartureTableList').is(':visible') && $('.pagination li.active a',$('#arrivalDepartureTableList').parents('.widget-body')).text()>1){

            $scope.filterArrivalDepartures($('.pagination li.active a',$('#arrivalDepartureTableList').parents('.widget-body')).text()>1);
    }else{
        $scope.filterArrivalDepartures(1);
    }
},5000);
```

Comment: [websockets](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/21/websockets-and-grails-a-chat-example/) could be a way

Comment: You need to check if db updated and update scope accordingly

Comment: where we have use web sockets in angularjs or grails.. else combine both.

Comment: @udays - Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470828/angular-ionic-badge-count-not-updating .

Comment: i have check it bro..but what i am exactly need means, when a user update something from one browser, it will automatically update in all user browser who have view this page view